# Entity Framework efficient use on large datasets

Tags: c#, sql, performance, entity-framework-4

I have a large dataset in my Entity Framework context - `table1` and a large `List<T>`, I need to count same values in the table1/list1 above.

I can do it two different  ways:

1. `jointCollection=table1.union(list1)` - and to check: the value of `list1.count+table1.count-jointCollection.count...`
2. to do count on `select table1 with multi condition(list1.count)`

My question is which method is more efficient?

Comment: Please define "in my context"? Are you trying to be smart by loading the complete table into memory instead of doing what is sensible, i.e. asking the database to count them?

Comment: my context is my complete table... guessing by your replay it is not that smart...

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to run SQL profiler while you run each one and find out!

However, if efficiency is paramount, I would recommend using a stored procedure imported in to EF as a function, as Linq to Entities adds additional overhead.

Comment: That implies and assumes he's using SQL Server ... which is likely, but not clear from the question.... EF works against other RDBMS systems, too